# Deploying GWT Application on Jetty

Tags: gwt, deployment, jetty

can someone explain how to deploy a gwt application under jetty along with configuring contexts and so one. I never did this, so i'm getting a bit confused with this

I have already compile my web application and created the war file

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is a standard servlet container so you can [deploy GWT as usual](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html).

Comment: Should i set context and so on .xml file or can i directly place the war file in jetty web app and run

Comment: You can simply put war file in webapp and Jetty will install it.

Comment: Actually my application uses Hibernate, on Eclipse with the jetty in development mode, everything works file but when i am placing it on tomcat or jetty, nothing is loaded from the database. The homepage does not loads completly bcause data is needed from database to make the homepage. So, the only problem i'm getting is actually making hibernate works